# Sequentially numbered directories creation in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, directory, sequential

I want to create sequential numbered directories given the max() existing one + 1, in Javascript - NodeJS.

For example if current dir has:

```
screenshots/ch33-001/
screenshots/ch33-002/
screenshots/ch33-003/
```

Script should create the next one:

```
screenshots/ch33-004/
```

If no directory exists yet, script should create the first:

```
screenshots/ch33-001/
```

I was using this in bash script but now i have to move this logic into nodejs:

```
browser=ch33
num=1
dirname=.
while [[ -d $dirname ]]; do
    let num++
    dirname=$(echo $browser- $num | awk '{ printf("%s%03d\n", $1, $2) }')
done
mkdir screenshots/$dirname
```

Comment: Look at Node's [FileSystem module doc](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) for things like checking file/directory existence and creating directories. The rest of it is just basic Javascript, the complete explanation of which is probably not what you are looking for (and if it was, that's too general to really ask here).

Comment: You're probably right, i was just being lazy. Feel free to improve my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var screenshot_dir = './screenshots';

var max = 0;
fs.readdirSync(screenshot_dir).forEach(function (file) {
    var match = file.match(/^ch33-(\d{3})$/);
    if (!match)
        return;

    var num = Number(match[1]);
    if (num > max)
        max = num;
});

fs.mkdirSync(path.join(screenshot_dir,
                       "ch33-" + ("000" + (max + 1)).slice(-3)));
```

Comment: Cool! I love regexps plus my version didn't support intermediate missing directories. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var browser = 'ch33';
var build_path = '.';
for (var i=1; fs.existsSync(build_path); i++) {
    build_path = path.join('./screenshots', browser + '-' + helpers.pad(i, 3));
};
fs.mkdirSync(build_path);
```

For the sake of completeness:

```
var helpers = {}; helpers.pad = function(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
};
```